# listenOnce() running twice in backbone.js event

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I had asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35785587/alert-window-in-a-different-view-after-form-submit-using-backbone-js) here that referred me to use using the backbone events. It works great, except that my event listener `onFormSubmit()` gets called twice. Normally I wouldn't care, but I have a function that toggles some states, and toggling this twice creates a problem.. I thought my view was being rendered twice (based on other answers on SO), but it does not appear to be so. I am trying to understand the 'why' behind what is happening here.. Here is some code (with non-relevant stuff removed)..

Here is my article form view that calls triggers the events on a form save and it gets triggered once (correct intended behavior) and it gets redirected back to the dashboard..

```
var PostView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: '#content',

  articletemplate: _.template($('#article-template-add').html()),

  initialize: function() {
    this.render();
  },

  render: function() {
    this.$el.html(this.articletemplate({}));
  },

  events: {
    "click .save": "savePost",
  },

  savePost: function() {
    var mypost = new PostModel();
    this.model = mypost;
    this.model.save(null, {
      success: function(model) {
        eventBus.trigger('formSubmitted', {
          message: "form submitted"
        });
        app.navigate("/", false);
      },
    });
  },
});
```

Here is my Dashboard view() that gets called after the form submit above.. Here is where onFormSubmit() executes twice (the console.log() gets printed twice).

```
var DashboardView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: '#content',
  dashboardtemplate: _.template($('#dashboard-template').html()),

  initialize: function() {
    this.listenToOnce(eventBus, 'formSubmitted', this.onFormSubmit);
    this.render();
  },

  onFormSubmit: function(datahere) {
    console.log("onFormSubmit called"); // *** This gets printed twice
  },

  render: function() {
    $(this.el).empty().html(this.dashboardtemplate(this.model.attributes));
  },
});
```

Now, I am beginning to think that there might be some problem in the main app routing?

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
  routes: {
    "": "dashboard",
    "article/add": "addarticle",
  },

  dashboard: function() {
    mydashview = new DashboardView();   
  },

  addarticle: function() {
    var articleView = new PostView();
  },
});

var eventBus = _.extend({}, Backbone.Events);
var app = new AppRouter();
Backbone.history.start();
```

**EDIT**

I updated the savePost() to include that the trigger is called in the callback of the this.model.save()..I've forced it to create a dummy model instead of taking it from a form. The good news is that I was able to recreate the behavior here: http://jsfiddle.net/okswxngv/  If you open your console, you can see the `onFormSubmit called` printing twice.

Comment: Can you confirm that savePost is only being called once.

Comment: Thanks @EricGuan. I updated the question with a jsfiddle where I am able to recreate the behaviour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is linked to the [ghost view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25916009/backbone-zombie-views-good-practice). Some call it zombie. The DashboardView is created every time you enter the root page, but never removed.

That is why he is going to exist, even if you link a new view to the #content div.

You can put a break point on DashboardView ->initialize and see that is called twice.

To better understand I have changed you code and added a name to the view (which is the date when it was created) and printed this name.

To get read of the problem you have to remove the unneeded [view](https://coderwall.com/p/jrnuiw/don-t-let-your-backbone-js-views-grow-up-to-be-zombies) when you create a new one.

Comment: Thanks - Can you provide the link the code that you changed? if you changed the code, you'd get a new url in jsfiddle.